# neo4j double UNWIND split

Tags: csv, neo4j, load

I Have the following .csv file

```
day,month,year,mps,party,subjectofquest,typeofquest,period,ministry<br/>
"1","1","2012","mp1,mp2,mp3","party1","subject1","type1","1","ministry1,ministry2"
```

I try to split the mps AND ministry cells after Mark Needhams guidance (http://java.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-load-csv-processing)
Each one of them can be done as standalone commands, but I cant figure how to it compined (after so much effort...)
The code that do the job for the mp cell is here:

```
load csv with headers from " file:///test/MESA2.csv " AS row<br/>  
  WITH row, split(row.mps, ",") AS mps<br/>  
  UNWIND mps AS mpname  <br/> 
  MERGE (p1:Question {questsub:row.subjectofquest})<br/>
  MERGE (p2:MP {mpname: mpname})<br/>
  MERGE (p3:Ministry{questministry: row.ministry})<br/>
  MERGE (p2)-[:ASKS_MKE]->(p1)<-[:REFERS]-(p3);<br/>
```

And i tried several syntaxes for the double UNWIND, here is one of the, but noone works:

```
load csv with headers from " file:///test/MESA2.csv " AS row <br/> 
  WITH row, split(row.mps, ",") AS mps <br/> 
  UNWIND mps AS mpname  <br/> 
  MERGE (p1:Question {questsub:row.subjectofquest})<br/>
  MERGE (p2:MP {mpname: mpname})<br/>
  MERGE (p2)-[:ASKS_MKE]->(p1)<br/>
  WITH row, split(row.ministry, ",") AS ypourgeio <br/> 
  UNWIND ypourgeio AS ypourgeio1<br/>
  MERGE (p3:Ypname{ypourgeio: ypourgeio}) <br/>
  MERGE (p1)-[:REFERS]->(p3)<br/>
```

Please help(I think I can split in excel through VB but its gonna be terrible!)
Thank you in advance!
Nektarios

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to help until you provide some example code.

Comment: Here my first try that accomplish the 1 cell split:  load csv with headers from " file:///test/MESA2.csv " AS row  
  WITH row, split(row.mps, ",") AS mps  
  UNWIND mps AS mpname   
  MERGE (p1:Question {questsub:row.subjectofquest})
  MERGE (p2:MP {mpname: mpname})
  MERGE (p3:Ministry{questministry: row.ministry})
  MERGE (p2)-[:ASKS_MKE]->(p1)<-[:REFERS]-(p3);

Answer (score 1):

Nektarios,

I'm not sure if you have variable numbers of subfields in both mps and ministries, but assuming that you do, and that you want to match all to all, try this:

```
LOAD csv WITH HEADERS FROM " file:///test/MESA2.csv " AS row
WITH row, SPLIT(row.mps, ",") AS mps, SPLIT(row.ministry, ",") as ministries
UNWIND mps AS mpname
WITH row, mpname, ministries
UNWIND ministries AS ministry
MERGE (p1:Question {questsub:row.subjectofquest})
MERGE (p2:MP {mpname: mpname})
MERGE (p3:Ministry{questministry: ministry})
MERGE (p2)-[:ASKS_MKE]->(p1)<-[:REFERS]-(p3);
```

I don't have access to a database to try it, so I may not have it right.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: Jim thank you very much, but it doesnt work (i think i tried that also sometime... )

ministries not defined (line 5, column 8)
"UNWIND ministries AS ministry"
        ^

Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax

Comment: The immediate problem is that you need to name the identifiers that you want to continue to use in the `WITH` clause. Something like `... WITH mpname, ministries ...`. If you don't name it then it's 'forgotten' and indeed `ministries` is not defined.

Comment: I added ministries to the WITH clause as jaderberg mentioned. Good catch!

Comment: :((  Seems like a double cross problem... again no... 

row not defined (line 6, column 30)
"MERGE (p1:Question {questsub:row.subjectofquest})"
                              ^

Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax. Now is the row that "feels" isolated...

Comment: I'd probably use `FOREACH` on those collections instead of `UNWIND`